# Spring @Async vs Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to convert the following method using WebFlux to avoid using @Async on the same.

```
@Async
@Override
public void notifyCallback(NotifyCallbackRequest request, String id) {

        startProcess(id);

}
```

Controller class:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@PostMapping("/notify-status/{id}")
public void notifyCallback(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody NotifyCallbackRequest request) {
    identityService.notifyCallback(request, id);
}
```

startProcess(id) is a method that makes an api call via webflux and returns a Mono  type.
I am interested that the caller immediately receives a ResponseStatus (HttpStatus.OK) despite what happens next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subscribe to your "async" task independently of your main reactive chain to start to make it run in the background as soon as the endpoint is called.

```
@Override
public void notifyCallback(NotifyCallbackRequest request, String id) {
        startProcess(id).subscribe();
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@PostMapping("/notify-status/{id}")
public Mono<Void> notifyCallback(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody NotifyCallbackRequest request) {
    identityService.notifyCallback(request, id);
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

You can demo this behaviour using the following endpoint example. If you call the endpoint, it will a 200 straight away and 10 seconds later it will log to your console

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/async", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Mono<Void> start() {
    Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .doOnNext(i -> LOGGER.info("we have waited 10 seconds"))
            .subscribe();

    return Mono.empty();
}
```